# Cookie is incomplete when reading in asp.net mvc but complete in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

If a cookie is sent with a request from the browser to an asp.net mvc endpoint, it is incomplete (sometimes). The content of the cookie is a small json object, that contains a few information (about 400 chars long).

The cookie is cut after 57 chars.

The cookies are added like this (`AddCookieObject`):

```
protected void AddCookieObject(string name, object o, DateTime expires = default(DateTime))
{
    AddCookieValue(name, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o), expires);
}

protected void AddCookieValue(string name, string value, DateTime expires = default(DateTime))
{
    var c = new HttpCookie(name, value);
    c.Expires = expires;
    AddCookie(c);
}

protected void AddCookie(HttpCookie cookie)
{
    var cookies = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies;
    cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

And if I read the cookies using `GetCookieObject<T>` it is incomplete and json parsing fails:

```
protected T GetCookieObject<T>(string name)
{
    var manager = new LogManager();
    string json = GetCookieValue(name);
    try
    {
        if (json != null)
            manager.Warning($"Cookie: {name}\r\n{json}");

        return json != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json) : default(T);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        manager.Warning($"Invalid cookie: {name}: {json ?? "<empty>"}");
        return default(T);
    }
}

protected string GetCookieValue(string name)
{
    var cookie = GetCookie(name);
    return cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null;
}

protected HttpCookie GetCookie(string name)
{
    var cookies = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies;
    return cookies.AllKeys.Contains(name) ? cookies[name] : null;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you check using fiddler or any network monitoring tool that the cookie is properly sent to the server ?